# python crear un dataframe a partir de una "plantilla"

Tags: python, pandas

la empresa trabaja en "plantillas", donde se asigna un costo por mes a la partida
para trabajar con un dataframe es dificil hacerlo si los costos estan en columnas de meses.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a partir de esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código que has avanzado para lograr dicho resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que buscas es precisamente lo que hace [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)/`pandas.DataFrame.melt`. Solo necesitas renombrar adecuadamente tus columnas previamente (para pasar de `Dev_ENE` a `Enero`) y, en caso de tener varias filas en el DataFrame de partida, ordenar al final convenientemente:

Primero vamos a crear un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""\
CAPITULO,CONCEPTO,PARTIDA,SUBPARTIDA,Dev_ENE,Dev_FEB,Dev_MAR,Dev_ABR,Dev_MAY,Dev_JUN,Dev_JUL,Dev_AGO,Dev_SEP,Dev_OCT,Dev_NOV,Dev_DIC
6000,6020,623,62301,55365,41067,20100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
6001,6030,754,75452,78788,24155,32555,0,0,455,0,0,57556,0,0,0
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    CAPITULO  CONCEPTO  PARTIDA  SUBPARTIDA  Dev_ENE  Dev_FEB  Dev_MAR  Dev_ABR  Dev_MAY  Dev_JUN  Dev_JUL  Dev_AGO  Dev_SEP  Dev_OCT Dev_NOV  Dev_DIC
> 0      6000      6020      623       62301    55365    41067    20100        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       0        0
> 1      6001      6030      754       75452    78788    24155    32555        0        0      455        0        0    57556        0       0        0
> ```

Con ello podemos proceder tal como se ha comentado antes:

```
# Renombrar columnas
rename_cols = ("Dev_ENE", "Dev_FEB", "Dev_MAR", "Dev_ABR", "Dev_MAY", "Dev_JUN",
               "Dev_JUL", "Dev_AGO", "Dev_SEP", "Dev_OCT", "Dev_NOV", "Dev_DIC"
               )
meses = ("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio",
         "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"
         )
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(rename_cols, meses)), inplace=True)


# Usamos melt para pivotar las columnas
df = df.melt(id_vars=["CAPITULO", "CONCEPTO", "PARTIDA", "SUBPARTIDA"], 
             var_name="Mes", 
             value_name="Monto"
             )

# Hacemos la columna Mes de tipo categórico, lo cual facilita ordenar por ejemplo
df["Mes"] = pd.Categorical(df["Mes"], categories=meses, ordered=True)

# Ordenamos las filas y reseteamos el índice
df.sort_values(by=["CAPITULO", "Mes"], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>     CAPITULO  CONCEPTO  PARTIDA  SUBPARTIDA         Mes  Monto
> 0       6000      6020      623       62301       Enero  55365
> 1       6000      6020      623       62301     Febrero  41067
> 2       6000      6020      623       62301       Marzo  20100
> 3       6000      6020      623       62301       Abril      0
> 4       6000      6020      623       62301        Mayo      0
> 5       6000      6020      623       62301       Junio      0
> 6       6000      6020      623       62301       Julio      0
> 7       6000      6020      623       62301      Agosto      0
> 8       6000      6020      623       62301  Septiembre      0
> 9       6000      6020      623       62301     Octubre      0
> 10      6000      6020      623       62301   Noviembre      0
> 11      6000      6020      623       62301   Diciembre      0
> 12      6001      6030      754       75452       Enero  78788
> 13      6001      6030      754       75452     Febrero  24155
> 14      6001      6030      754       75452       Marzo  32555
> 15      6001      6030      754       75452       Abril      0
> 16      6001      6030      754       75452        Mayo      0
> 17      6001      6030      754       75452       Junio    455
> 18      6001      6030      754       75452       Julio      0
> 19      6001      6030      754       75452      Agosto      0
> 20      6001      6030      754       75452  Septiembre  57556
> 21      6001      6030      754       75452     Octubre      0
> 22      6001      6030      754       75452   Noviembre      0
> 23      6001      6030      754       75452   Diciembre      0
> ```

Comment: gracias #FJSevilla, tu respuesta me sirvio, ya solo le agregué
>>>list(df.columns.values)
>>>meses1=pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2019-12-12', 
              freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%b").tolist()

Comment: gracias #FJSevilla, tu respuesta me sirvio, ya solo le agregué
>>>list(df.columns.values)
cree una lista llamada meses a partir del resultado llamada rename_columns, cree una lista de meses con un rango de un año:
>>>meses=pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2019-12-12', 
              freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%b").tolist()

renombré
>>>df1.rename(columns=dict(zip(rename_columns, meses)), inplace=True)

pequeñas adecuaciones al dataframe y voilá

Comment: siento mucho si el formato no se adecua a lo que estais acostumbrados a ver, es mi primera vez en stackoverflow !
:)

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya pude solucionar el problema con la respuesta de #FCSevilla, estoy muy agradecido.

Ya estaba pensando hasta en hacer una funcion o algo mas loco.

saludos.